# Chrome: history -> reload N tabs, can we make chrome actually reload some or all the tabs?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome has the option to reload a set of N tabs (where N is a positive integer like 60), but I find that it doesn't actually reload the tabs until you click on a tab, and then only it may attempt to reload that tab. How can we make it actually reload (go out to the web sites indicated by the URLs and actually request the content again) all or a selected subset of the tabs, when we go to History -> Reload N tabs? The motivation is that we may want to actually be seeing refreshed contents when we go to those tabs, rather than the previous version of those pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an exact answer, and it has been 3 months, but by googling, I have found chrome extensions that can reload your specified tabs at specified intervals. For example, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-simple-auto-refresh/ohoicclioikehjddmoohhahbkmbohlch/related?hl=en , that I will try.

EDITED Feb 12 2021
I'm not sure if that extension is working properly, but meanwhile, I found another one, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reload-all-tabs/midkcinmplflbiflboepnahkboeonkam/related?hl=en so if I just put all the tabs that I wish to reload in a separate window, and use this extension, it does a reload with one click. Cool.